# i am using toastr js . But toastr notification not showing on mac book pro

Tags: javascript, jquery

toastr.js notification is working fine on window safari and chrome and goole also. But not working on Mac book pro safari ? i think jquery is breaking at this point.

```
 window.on('cart.updateitemquantity', function (data) {
                    ajax.json({
                        url: '@Url.Action("updateitemquantity", "shopping")',
                        data: data,
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response.success) {
                                window.location = window.location;
                            } else {
                                toastr.error(response.message, "We were unable to update the items quantity.");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Kindly share what have you tried till now, only then we'll be able to assist you further

Comment: have you checked the console on mac?

Comment: yes i check it. but its not giving me any error.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma i am using this code.

Comment: @umarmunir Kindly edit your question and add a working code snippet or provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: @umarmunir do you get any errors on browser's console? and which browser are you using on mac?

Comment: first try to run `toastr.error('test', "just a test")` outside the ajax call -- if it wont appear you'll know that you do not properly initialize the toastr library, and if the toast will show, you will know the issue is in the ajax.